# Using Flask to run an looping function

Tags: python, function, api, flask, flask-restful

How to use Flask for chatbot model function in Python

I'm Currently implementing Chatbot which recurring through Decision Tree and asking the user to reply with "yes or no" until the chatbot wants to the answer.

Here is the Code:

```
rom tkinter import YES
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn import tree
p = pd.read_csv("MixedSet2.csv")

data = p

# %%
X =  data.iloc[:, :-1].values
""" print(X) """
y = data.iloc[:, -1].values
""" print(y) """


# %%
dimensionality_reduction = data.groupby(data['problem']).max()
""" yes """


# %%
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder.fit_transform(y)
""" print(y) """

# %%
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)

# %%
model


# %%
cols     = data.columns
cols     = cols[:-1]

# %%
importances = model.feature_importances_
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]
features = cols

# %%
from sklearn.tree import _tree

# %%
def execute_bot():

    print("Please reply with yes/Yes or no/No for the following symptoms") 
    def print_problem(node):
        #print(node)
        node = node[0]
        #print(len(node))
        val  = node.nonzero() 
        #print(val)
        problem = labelencoder.inverse_transform(val[0])
        return problem
    def tree_to_code(tree, feature_names):
        tree_ = tree.tree_
        #print(tree_)
        feature_name = [
            feature_names[i] if i != _tree.TREE_UNDEFINED else "undefined!"
            for i in tree_.feature
        ]
        symptoms_present = []
        def recurse(node, depth):
            indent = "  " * depth
            if tree_.feature[node] != _tree.TREE_UNDEFINED:
                name = feature_name[node]
                threshold = tree_.threshold[node]
                print(name + " ?")
                ans = input()
                ans = ans.lower()
                if ans == 'yes':
                    val = 1
                else:
                    val = 0
                if  val <= threshold:
                    recurse(tree_.children_left[node], depth + 1)
                else:
                    symptoms_present.append(name)
                    recurse(tree_.children_right[node], depth + 1)
            else:
                present_problem = print_problem(tree_.value[node])
                
                print('The Model Suggests:')
                print()
                print( "You may have: " +  present_problem )
                print()
                row = CarDiagnose[CarDiagnose['problem'] == present_problem[0]]
                print('Description: ', str(row['Description'].values))
                print()
                print('Inspection List: ', str(row['InspectionList'].values))
    
        recurse(0, 1)
    
    tree_to_code(model,cols)




# %%
""" D = pd.read_csv('CarDiagnose.csv') """

Isnpection_dataset = pd.read_csv("CarDiagnose.csv", names = ['Description','InspectionList'])

problem = dimensionality_reduction.index
problem = pd.DataFrame(problem)

CarDiagnose = pd.DataFrame()

CarDiagnose['Description'] = np.nan
CarDiagnose['InspectionList'] = np.nan

CarDiagnose['problem'] = np.nan
CarDiagnose['problem'] = problem['problem']


CarDiagnose['Description'] = Isnpection_dataset['Description']
CarDiagnose['InspectionList'] = Isnpection_dataset['InspectionList']


# %%
execute_bot()

# %%
import pickle

filename = 'savedmodel.sav'
pickle.dump(model,open(filename,'wb'))

# %%
load_model = pickle.load(open(filename,'rb'))
```

And I'm trying to use Flask to integrate it with flutter, I saved the Decision tree model in `.sav`

```
import pickle

filename = 'savedmodel.sav
pickle.dump(model,open(filename,'wb'))
```

and imported the the whole `.py` project to Flask to execute my Function :

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
from NLPyesornoCarDiagnoses import execute_bot

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('savedmodel.sav', 'rb'))

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return execute_bot()    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

There Are two problem, when i type "Flask run" on the terminal it executes the execute_bot function first before starting the server:

> `C:\Users\saiko_sore\StudioProjects\FlaskDemo>flask run Please reply with yes/Yes or no/No for the following symptoms symptomA_The car shakes ? yes symptomC_It happens while driving at a certain speed ? yes The Model Suggests: ['You may have: Check the balance of the four wheels'] Description:  ['The constant heating and cooling of the exhaust manifold can cause leaks. You may catch a small crack before it becomes large enough to make a noise and become a more serious problem.'] Inspection List:  ["1) Secure the vehicle on a level surface making sure the vehicle will not roll or lean when jacked up. 2) Using a jack, lift up the vehicle. Every vehicle comes from the factory with a jack. To locate and properly use this jack see the owners manual. The owners manual will inform you what proper jacking locations should be used. 3) Secure the vehicle with  jack stands on both sides for safety before starting any work. The pinch welds or the frame rails are the two best locations to use. Do not rely on the jack to hold the vehicle up while working. 4) Inspect the entire exhaust system for damage. If your system has multiple sections that are rusted, cracked, or causing exhaust leaks, it is recommended that you install a new exhaust system into your vehicle.']"] Debug mode: off WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead. Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 Press CTRL+C to quit`

Second thing is after the bot finished it shows another error:

> `ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET] Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\saiko_sore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "C:\Users\saiko_sore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1487, in full_dispatch_request return self.finalize_request(rv) File "C:\Users\saiko_sore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1506, in finalize_request response = self.make_response(rv) File "C:\Users\saiko_sore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1801, in make_response raise TypeError( TypeError: The view function for 'home' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement. 127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2023 03:05:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -`

Here is the execute_bot Function looks like while running

> `Please reply with yes/Yes or no/No for the following symptoms symptomA_The car shakes ? yes symptomC_It happens while driving at a certain speed ? yes The Model Suggests: ['You may have: Check the balance of the four wheels'] Description:  ['The constant heating and cooling of the exhaust manifold can cause leaks. You may catch a small crack before it becomes large enough to make a noise and become a more serious problem.'] Inspection List:  ["1) Secure the vehicle on a level surface making sure the vehicle will not roll or lean when jacked up. 2) Using a jack, lift up the vehicle. Every vehicle comes from the factory with a jack. To locate and properly use this jack see the owners manual. The owners manual will inform you what proper jacking locations should be used. 3) Secure the vehicle with  jack stands on both sides for safety before starting any work. The pinch welds or the frame rails are the two best locations to use. Do not rely on the jack to hold the vehicle up while working. 4) Inspect the entire exhaust system for damage. If your system has multiple sections that are rusted, cracked, or causing exhaust leaks, it is recommended that you install a new exhaust system into your vehicle.']"]`

Comment: Don't make us click on images to see the problem.  Post all errors as plain text.

Comment: why did you put flutter in your tags?

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm new to StackOverflow.

Acknowledged.

Comment: @Rationalist Wrong typo, sorry for the mistake and thanks for announcing me.

Comment: View functions are supposed to return some kind of HTML or HTTP response.  But `home()` doesn't, because `execute_bot()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Also, why in the world are you using Flask to run a plain text application?  Flask is supposed to be for web pages!

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for your quick answering, regarding for your comments I'm currently working on a Flutter chatbot application as front-end for my graduation project and modeling in python DT based on historical data which contains symptoms and finally diagnoses the car.

And I'm using this DT for the project and it's works well and I need to integrate it to flutter. 

Sorry again for the inconvenience, and i'm very thankful for your support.

Comment: @JohnGordon Updated the code for the whole '.py' model

Comment: @JohnGordon any suggestion on how to use return method on >` execute_bot()` function

Comment: No, because as I said, view functions are supposed to return HTML.  But there's nothing here that is HTML.  I have no idea how you intend this to be an actual web page.